# Scaling down a BMP image in C

Tags: c

```
 int main(void) {
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    //Input File
    FILE* infile;
    infile = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");

    //Vars for image
    char bm[2];
    int imageSize;
    int fileSize;
    int width, height;
    char restOfDataOne[12];
    char restOfDataTwo[28];

    //Read Header Info
    fread(bm, 1, 2, infile);
    fread(&fileSize, 1, 4, infile);
    imageSize = fileSize - 54;
    fread(restOfDataOne, 1, 12, infile);
    fread(&width, sizeof(int), 1, infile);
    fread(&height, sizeof(int), 1, infile);
    fread(restOfDataTwo, 1, 28, infile);
    int rowWidth = width * 3;
    //Read Image Data
    unsigned char image[height][(width * 3)];
    fread(image, sizeof(char), imageSize, infile);

    //Close
    fclose(infile);

    //#################################################
    //Small BMP
    //#################################################
    FILE* smallOut;
    smallOut = fopen("small.bmp", "wb");

    //Small Vars
    int imageSizeSmall = imageSize / 4;
    int fileSizeSmall = imageSizeSmall + 54;
    int widthSmall = width / 2;
    int heightSmall = height / 2;
    int smallRowWidth = widthSmall * 3;
    unsigned char imageSmall[heightSmall][smallRowWidth];

    //Image Data
    int c, d, e;
    //For every 4 pixels.. store one in small image
    for(c = 0; c < rowWidth; c++) {
       for(d = 0; d < height; d++) {
            //imageSmall[d/2][c/2] = image[d][c];
            for(e = 0; e < 3; e++) {
                //grab every 1 out of 4 and place into small?
            }
       }
    }
```

So I have the following code which reads the bmp image, then I need to scale it down and output it to the smaller version which is half the width and half the height, therefore being 4 times smaller in all. So I know I have to grab 1 out of every 3 pixels? and put it into my new smallImage, but I have tried multiple things with nested for loops and just can't get the algorithm down. I have viewed multiple posts here on stackexchange but people are using libraries, which I cannot use. (Homework). I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, just looking for someone to point me in the right direction or give me a hint?
Full code here. 
https://pastebin.com/ZVmXtmCx

Comment: Well I need one out of every 4 pixels, which each pixel is 3 bytes? I think

Comment: Which [image scaling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) are you trying to implement?

Comment: I am trying to simply scale the image down to half the width and half the size. So running for loops over my 2d array (which is holding my original image data without the BMP header stuff) and then place every 4th pixel into my new small image array. I also need to do the same thing by creating a bigger image (4x the size)

Comment: I guess maybe the term resizing would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice and detailed study for your problem at the following address:

http://www.davdata.nl/math/bmresize.html

I quote:

> This is done by scanning these pixels, left to right, top to bottom
>   while projecting the destination pixel over the source bitmap.

Comment: I have read through that, as that is where I got the idea in the first place for my code. I am  just having trouble translating that into my 2d array format with my for loops

Comment: Then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672744/how-to-scale-a-bmp-image-using-c-and-just-the-iostream-and-stdio-headers

Comment: @Fabien-- you aren't providing answers, you are just finding links. These should be comments.

Comment: In fact I had another answer initially, and whiped it out... So yeah, not the best answer but well... Remains. :-p

Comment: lol. Well I figured out the imageSmall part. Just trying to figure out the imageBig part. Will post results when and if i figure it out.[